# Perforce in the Cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, perforce

I've a free license of Perforce (2 users), and I noticed that they propose in their website  an evaluation of perforce in the cloud (through Amazon EC2).

Has someone ever used Perforce in the Cloud ? and are there any concerns or risks to use it for commercial apps ?

Thank you

Comment: This is the first that I've heard of the service and I have to say that I'm very interested. I'm going to try it out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perforce in the Cloud is pretty new, but it should work just fine, as long as your pipe to the internet is fat enough. There's not much difference between Perforce in the Cloud and a distributed server architecture, which has been used for years.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much concern whether you use perforce in your Local Company network or EC2, The only difference is infrastructure management and security concern in Amazon EC2.. You should have some Amazpon Ec2 Expert who can help you out setting up the server there.

However, Perforce in Cloud is still in final phase of evaluation and company provide lots of info about it in following URL...

http://kb.perforce.com/article/1360

http://www.perforce.com/downloads/try_perforce_free